# How to delete listview item from database using button?

Tags: android

Now I'm using onItemLongClick to delete.
Each listview item have delete button. 
I want to delete using the button.
The below code is my onItemLongClick code.

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Aview item = mAviewList.get(position);
    mAviewList.remove(position);
    aviewDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName + " WHERE id = '" + item.getId() + "';");
    getAviewData(materialCalendarView.getCurrentDate().getDate());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I want to using button not a onItemLongClick Event

Comment: `button.setOnClickListener()` and executive above code there

Comment: why dont you add onClickListener ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the way this is done is that you define an XML layout file for your list item that includes a delete button (you can hide the delete button by default and only reveal it if the user swipes left if you want to be fancy).  In your custom list adapter, when you inflate the layout, you will get the Button from the layout and set an onClickListener for that button that uses the Position passed to the getView() method of the adapter.  Here is an example that would go in the getView() method of your adapter:

```
    Button btnDelete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.trip_delete_in_list);
    btnDelete.setTag(position);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer position = (Integer)v.getTag();
            fragment.deleteItemList(position);
        }
    });

    btnDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Are you using a custom list adapter?  That's the best way.

Comment: I'm using a custom adapter.. I even use dialog... that's why I can't use the code.. I have too many file haha...